# Managing/Updating headers in Apache Server

Tags: apache, http, web, http-headers, webserver

We are using Apache as our Web server for our CRM application (Siebel) . We continuosly deploy new JS and CSS files on the CRM application in 15 days Currently we have the following setting.

`FileETag None
ExpiresActive On`

`<IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 5 days"
   ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 5 days"
   ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 5 days"
   ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 5 days"
   ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 5 days"
   ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 5 days"
   ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 5 days"
   AddType image/x-icon .ico
   ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 5 days"
</IfModule>`

In this case if we have a Hotfix release we have to ask the end users to clear their cache so that the new files can be reflected from their side else they have to wait till the objects expire and are auto refreshed.

If we set it to a lower value than the requests to the web server increase and the load increases on web server.

I would like to know is there any mechanism.

1) To auto update the new files on end user machine automatically when a new file is placed .

2) To set expiration of folder level rather than a file level.

Thanks

Comment: Code formatting

Comment: Hi Stuart ,Can you please explain .

Comment: Sorry @user77243 - I edited your post, and it asked for the reasons for the edit - to which I added "Code Formatting" - I've no idea why this came through as a comment :/

Answer (score 0):

In response to `point 1)`

I'd suggest using versioning at the URL level.

I.E `mysite.com/lib/js.js?v=1`, `mysite.com/lib/style.css?v=1` (etc.. etc..)

When you roll out a new version, update this to v=x (and so on).

There is no way of forcing a client to flush it's cache, mainly due to all the browsers being implemented different (they'd all have to implement this), and it would no doubt be some risk of security.

As for `point 2)` maybe this question might help:

[ServerOverflow - Apache: ExpiresByType per directory?](https://serverfault.com/questions/564314/apache-expiresbytype-per-directory)

Comment: Hi Stuart,

I see the tag <Directory /var/www/js/expire_fast> being added to the httpd.conf file to make certain files expire faster. Can you please let us know what does this expire_fast indicate in term of days/hours.

1)As in the example, we see below the access plus et to 60 minutes, in this case, how soon will the files expire for expire_fast.

2)In our case, if the access plus is set to 5 days when will the files expire.

2) Is there any way to set a value for the expire fast.

Comment: @user77243 it looks like expire_fast is just a directory, which is set at 60 minutes expiry by the config. expire_fast isn't an apache thing, just what they've called the dir.

Comment: You could call the directory foobar or dir, or anything you want, expire_fast is purely the name they've called it